# How to iterate each document/text and run through tfidf vectorizer store output in sparse matrix

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to run text corpus through tfidf vectorizer while storing each document/text tfidf output am getting following error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tocoo'
```

Below is my code.

```
for i in range(test_reviews_df.shape[0]):
   final_tf_idf=[]               
   final_tf_idf.append(text_vectorizer_tst.transform(
                       [test_reviews_df['formated_reviews'].values[i]]))
    final_tf_idf=final_tf_idf.tocoo()
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  `final_tf_idf` is a list.  What were you expecting it to be?  What kind of object has a `tocoo` method?

Comment: Normally when we iterate, appending to a list, we initial the list outside the loop, and finish converting the list outside the loop as well.

Comment: @hpaulj,all i wanted to know how to store tfidf value of each document and store in sparse matrix format.

Comment: You need to  first understand how your loop works, or should work.  There is a difference between a list that contains `tfidf` values, and a `tfidf` value.